# What exactly happens in least squares estimation when two predictors are almost perfectly or perfectly correlated?

Tags: regression, linear-regression

So I know in statistical software in linear regression, when two predictors are highly correlated, the software can't give you any results.

What exactly is the cause of this? Is it because there can be too many solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know anything about linear algebra? In particular, do you know what the rank of a matrix is, and do you know what a singular value or at least an eigenvalue is?

Comment: I know up to rank but not singular/eigenvalues are yet.

Comment: OK. When two predictors are *exactly* correlated, what happens is that the matrix $A^T A$ in the normal equations $A^T A x = A^T b$ is not full rank anymore, because the matrix $A$ itself doesn't have full column rank. When two predictors are not exactly correlated but are strongly correlated, the problem of solving the least squares system has an exact solution, but it has a bad "condition number", which makes it difficult to solve numerically. Part of this bad condition number is caused by forming the normal equations (so other methods are better), but part of it is inherent to the problem.

Comment: If that answers your question then I'll make it an answer.

Comment: The first part I understand, but I don't understand the bad condition number.   Any way you could explain with eigenvalues anyways as I am trying to learn that stuff.  I just haven't gotten there yet in my book. Thanks!

Comment: Say $A$ is $m \times n$ with $m>n$ and it has rank $n$ (the normal situation where we consider least squares for $Ax=b$). $A$ will have a large condition number for solving a least squares system if its smallest singular value is much smaller than its largest singular value. In particular this happens if the ratio of the largest to smallest singular value is large (say greater than $10^6$). A singular value of $A$ is just the square root of an eigenvalue of $A^T A$, so it has to do with the spread in the eigenvalues of $A^T A$.

Comment: (Cont.) Geometrically what is going on is basically that $A$ maps two lines that are at a large angle from one another into two lines that are at a small (but nonzero) angle from one another. This makes numerical computation have problems, because of roundoff error, slow convergence of iterative methods (whose convergence rate estimates can often be given explicitly in terms of the condition number), or both.